# Rest Api Hit Difference B/w Browser and Postman

Tags: java, rest, api, http

I am calling a REST API using postman and a Browser.
Each gives me the same result but,
I need know the how to identify which requests come from postman and which come from a browser.
I need to stop hits from Postman.

Comment: Get headers from the reqeust and look for the "postman-token". if the header has it, your request come from postman

Comment: Your problem is indistinguishable from the hooting of monkeys.  Specifically, Postman is one of an ever growing number of REST clients.  In general, the job of a REST client tool (like Postman) is to simulate a browser.  If the tool is doing a good job, then you cannot determine the source (browser vs Postman).  Also, there is a version of Postman that runs in the browser.

Comment: @DwB - Tho what you said is true, he can always use tricks to go around it. And that is what he asked for, and idea how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add an additional identifier to Postman request - like Header.

**Under Headers tab in Postman, click under New Key and write some name like myFlag, then under Value part set something like "postman"**

You can pass other useful data in this manner. And for some servers you will need to setup stuff before you can use them, for example authorization tokens etc..

Now on the backend side (in part of code where you handle request for API in question) you should be able to read all headers including the one we added. 
Say if this one is present it's a postman open a new block with empty line or console block in it and set breakpoint to that line

Answer (score 0):

Since you are the one making the Postman requests, there is a built in option under SETTINGS - GENERAL - HEADERS with a toggle for "Send Postman Token Header" and you could filter based on this specific header.

You could, of course, create a customer header as already mentioned as well and filter based on that. I am not sure if it is possible to STOP them since at the minimum you need to accept the request in order to filter it out.

Although not part of your question, if you are trying to stop someone else that is using Postman to call your API with Postman, you can try the toggle, but, of course, they can just turn off the toggle and you would not know where it came from.